# Unable to load JSON data in html file

Tags: json

I am trying to create a table loading the information from a local json file, but first I am not being able to pull data from the JSON file to my html, this is my approach until now.

This is my JS,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
        $.getJSON('baseball_stats.json',function(data){
            console.log('success');
            $.each(data,function(i,data){
                $('ul').append('<li>'+data.Player+' '+data.Team+'</li>');
            });
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
```

This is a part of my JSON file,

```
[
 {
   "Player": "LeMahieu",
   "Team": "COL",
   "Pos": "2B",
   "G": 146,
   "AB": 552,
   "R": 104,
   "H": 192,
   "2B": 32,
   "3B": 8,
   "HR": 11,
   "RBI": 66,
   "BB": 66,
   "SO": 80,
   "SB": 11,
   "CS": 7,
   "AVG": 0.348,
   "OBP": 0.416,
   "SLG": 0.495,
   "OPS": 0.911
 },
```

and this is my HTML,

```
<body>
<h1>BASEBALL STATS</h1>
<ul>
  <li id="player"></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: While it looks like it should work, I suggest setting an id on the <ul> tag (.e.g, <ul id="playerlist"> and using $('#playerlist') instead of $('ul'). That will eliminate the inevitable problems that would occur if/when you added another <ul> to the page.

Comment: the data is not showing up at all, I have been scratching my head for a while now.

Comment: $.each(data,function(i,data) - change 'data' inside the function to something else - Javascript might be getting a bit confused and it is poor style even if it works. Add a console.log inside the $.each function to see if you're getting there.

Comment: still not working, am I accessing the data key correctly?